# How can I allow users to compile .resources.dll files for my application?

Tags: c#, .net-core, localization, monogame

I have a monogame-built game on steam, and would like to offer modders the ability to translate the in-game text into their native language and upload language packs to the steam workshop.

I've transferred most of my in-game text to a .resx file (Localization.resx) using the Visual Studio designer, and I can create language packs myself in visual studio simply by copying that and renaming it with the culture name (eg. Localization.en-US.resx). Visual Studio takes care of compiling it into a .resources.dll file, and it gets loaded if I change the CurrentUICulture.

However, when I try compiling the resx file on another computer (using ResGen.exe and al.exe) and copying the resultant dll into place (a subfolder named after the region: eg. MyGame\en-US), nothing happens. The game continues to use the default strings. These are the commands I'm using to compile it:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\ResGen.exe" Localization.resx
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\al.exe" /t:lib /embed:Localization.resources /culture:en-US /out:MyGame.resources.dll
```

I thought satellite assemblies and resource files were built for this purpose, but I'm starting to think I've misunderstood the technology.

Answer (score 1):

Resource files are statically linked(pointed to) in the executable assembly. Adding files alone will not work.

You must provide a dynamic loader for any non-compile time resources.

A better solution would be to allow translations to be uploaded, verified and compiled into a new assembly. That you release.